# What is the fastest way to join two iterables (or sequences) in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

Say I want to create an `Iterable` by joining multiple `Iterable`s. What would be the fastest way to do so?

[Documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html) for `ListBuffer`'s `++=` says that it

> Appends all elements produced by a TraversableOnce to this list buffer.

which sounds like it appends the elements one by one and hence should take `Ω(size of iterable to append)` time. I want something that joins the two `Iterable`s in `O(1)` time. Does `:::` method of `List` runs in `O(1)` time? Documentation simply states that it

> Adds the elements of a given list in front of this list.

I also checked out [performance characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) of scala collections but it says nothing about joining two collections.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Stream`:

```
Stream(a, b, c).flatten
```

or concatenate iterators (this gives you `Stream` at runtime anyway)

```
(a.iterator ++ b.iterator ++ c.iterator).toIterable
```

(assuming that `a`, `b` and `c` are `Iterable[Int]`)

That will give you something along the lines of `O(number of collections to join)`

---

Streams are evaluated on demand, so only little memory allocation will happen for closures until you actually request any elements. Converting to anything else is unavoidably `O(n)`.

Comment: > Converting to anything else is unavoidably O(n).
That doesn't sound like any improvement over `:::`. Is it?

Comment: Any simple linked list can perform this task in `O(number of collections to join)`. Order is not important. I am kinda new to Scala...

Comment: @Kakaji don't confuse number of collections with their size. In here, number of collections is 3 (a, b and c).

Comment: Oh I see. That sounds great!